# Why does "touch åäö" end up as "\303\245\303\244\303\266"?

Tags: macos, unicode, encoding, zsh

I ran the command `touch åäö` in zsh wanting to create a file name with some exotic characters.

I then used a file upload dialog inside a HTML page to upload this file to a server. In this case, the non-ascii byte sequence that I have ends up in the `Content-Disposition` HTTP header and creates an error.

So, I used this function to clean up the file name

```js
function ascii(latin1: string): string {
  latin1 = latin1.replace(/[\u00C0-\u00C5]/g, "A")
  latin1 = latin1.replace(/[\u00E0-\u00E5]/g, "a")

  latin1 = latin1.replace(/[\u00D2-\u00D6]/g, "O")
  latin1 = latin1.replace(/[\u00F2-\u00F6]/g, "o")

  latin1 = latin1.replace(/[^\-\.0-9A-Z_a-z]+/g, "-")

  return latin1
}
```

Imagine my surprise when the file name came out as `a-a-o` and not `aao` what is even more diabolical is that if I change `latin1.replace(/[\u00E0-\u00E5]/g, "a")` to instead substitute with `"w"` I get `"ŵ"` back (note the hat)!?

How precisely did the the string get loaded into the JavaScript environment with some crazy encoding and what encoding is the file system using here really?

Comment: `"\303\245\303\244\303\266"` is _octal_ representation of UTF-8 encoded string `åäö`…

Answer (score 0):

the reason was:

this "String" is actually a chain of unicodes

```
\303\245\303\244\303\266
```

if we group them in 2 unicodes chunks you get

> \303\245
> this is OCT 303 (or HEX C3)  and OCT 245 (or HEX A5)
> so \303\245 is the same as C3A5 which is the unicode for **å**

[image]

same applies for the rest of the codes..

> \303\244

> \303\266

Comment: Ok, octal. Got it. This doesn't explain though how the string got messed up. It it was UTF-8 on disk how did it get destroyed when loaded into the browser? This is the really perplexing part to me.